# Stop the HTTP request in Client

Tags: java, javascript, httpwebrequest

I have the scenario to the HTTP request which is hitted from the browser address bar and i need to redirect to different URL on the client side.

Is there any way to Abort the HTTP request and redirects to the new URL.

Comment: You could try window.location = "http://www.yourredirectwebpage.com;

Comment: Sounds like you want to stop the user from being able to leave your site if they type a new URL into the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you were able to do it, it would be a large vulnerability. The reason being is that the http request would signify request headers being sent back to your browser, indicating that you're already on your way to the other site. If this could be done via javascript, it would definitely be a hack, as it would allow you to redirect a site such as *fakebank.com* instead of *mybank.com*.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this using just javascript.

You need to capture the request on the server side and make a 3XX request setting the `Location` http header to the URL you want to redirect your users to